# Update only certain columns in DB using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have an entity that I know already exists in the database but which is not currently being tracked by the context. I force the context to track the entity using the Attach method on DbSet. Then set `'IsModified' = true` for necessary properties. But `EF` tries to update every property in db table and `SaveChanges()` method throws exception that some properties is required and can't be empty. Though I mark only one property as modified. 
I'm using EF v.6.0.

Here is my code:

```
public bool ChangeState(int id, bool state)
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = new T {ID = id, Hidden = state};

            _context.Set<T>().Attach(obj);

            _context.Entry(obj).Property(x => x.Hidden).IsModified = true;
            return _context.SaveChanges() == 1;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            ...
        }            
    }
}
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: Which version of EF?

Comment: You could try `_context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`. (before `Attach`)

Comment: great.. it works fine. thank you. Unfortunately I don't have reputation enough to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to have an answer for this question , I'll repeat @Stephen Muecke answer here :

---

You could try `_context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`
Please do not vote me, the credit is for @Stephen Muecke